# how to solve $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{n} \log \left(\sum_{k=2}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate the following limit?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{1}{n} \log \left(\sum_{k=2}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)$$
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq9IH.jpg)

Comment: Write it as a Riemann sum?

Comment: @Jack No thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $1\leq k\leq 2^n$, we have
$$
  1\leq k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
so that
$$
2^n \leq \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq 2^n \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2^{n+\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
Taking the logarithm (I assume in base 2 (?)),
$$
n \leq \log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq n+\frac{1}{n}.
$$
and you can conclude by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: if k=2 Starts How can?

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean?

Comment: I edit . look . k=2

Comment: The same argument  will apply, try to do so and you'll see. (That's a good way to check you understand the answer.) Also, in the future try to refrain from changing your question after it has been answered.

Comment: $$n \leq \log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq n+\frac{1}{n}.$$   1 $$1\leq\frac{1}{n} \log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq n+\frac{2}{n}$$ $$ \lim_{ x \to \infty }\frac{1}{n} \log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}}=?$$

Comment: The answer is 1, if the logarithm is in base 2.

Comment: @Expal1975 In your comment above: (1) why did $1/n$ become $2/n$ in the right-hand side? And (2) why didn't you divide the right-hand side by $n$, as you did for the LHS?

Comment: @ See my photo by I tried

Comment: Basically, from what I wrote you get, dividing the inequalities by $n$, $$
1 \leq \frac{1}{n} \log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq 1+\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$ and the limit is immediate. If you insist on (like in your subsequent edit) starting at the index $k=2$, then you have instead (only the lower bound changes)
$$
1 + \frac{1}{n}\log(1- \frac{1}{2^n}) \leq \frac{1}{n} \log\sum_{k=2}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq 1+\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
and you get the same limit.

Comment: I edited . look photo

Comment: No: look at what I wrote. You have the solution above: **read it**, and ask questions on *specific* points you don't understand, if any.

Comment: why ?$$1+1/n \log(1-1/2^n) \leq 1/n\log\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} k^{\frac{1}{n^2}} $$

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^{2^n} k^{1/n^2} \geq (2^n -1)\cdot 1 = 2^n -1$, since now you have $2^n -1$ terms in the sum (each being at least $1$).  And $\log(2^n-1) = \log(2^n) + \log(1-1/2^n)=n+ \log(1-1/2^n)$.

Comment: @Expal1975 By the way, if you are satisfied with the above, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the $\checkmark$ sign on the left.